# Python convert WKT polygon to row wise points

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, points, polygons, wkt

```
"POLYGON ((12 13,22 23,16 17,22 24))",101,Something,100000
"POLYGON ((10 12,40 42,46 34,16 24,88 22,33 24,18 20 ))",102,another,200000
```

How can I get something like below in a csv file:

UID(like 101,102 etc) represents an unique identifier for each polygon.

```
UID#1,County,population,Point#1_Lat,Point#1_Long
UID#1,County,population,Point#2_Lat,Point#2_Long
UID#1,County,population,Point#3_Lat,Point#3_Long
UID#1,County,population,Point#n_Lat,Point#n_Long

UID#2,County,population,Point#1_Lat,Point#1_Long
UID#2,County,population,Point#2_Lat,Point#2_Long
UID#2,County,population,Point#3_Lat,Point#3_Long
UID#2,County,population,Point#n_Lat,Point#n_Long
```

Comment: In your first row, is "Something" the county and "100000" the population?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using [`pyparsing`](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/). Let me know if that doesn't work for you - it shouldn't be too difficult to come up with something that only uses the standard library (e.g. `re`, etc.), but it will definitely be uglier.

```
import csv
from pyparsing import Group, Literal, OneOrMore, Optional, Word
from pyparsing import delimitedList
from pyparsing import alphas, nums

data = """
"POLYGON ((12 13,22 23,16 17,22 24))",101,Something,100000
"POLYGON ((10 12,40 42,46 34,16 24,88 22,33 24,18 20 ))",102,another,200000
"""

def parse_line(line):
    latitude = Word(nums)
    longitude = Word(nums)
    point = Group(latitude + longitude)
    point_sequence = delimitedList(point, delim=',')

    name = Word("POLYGON").suppress()
    paren_left = Literal("((").suppress()
    paren_right = Literal("))").suppress()
    quote = Literal('"').suppress()
    polygon = Group(quote + name + paren_left + point_sequence + paren_right + quote)

    uid = Word(nums)
    county = Word(alphas)
    population = Word(nums)
    sep = Literal(",").suppress()
    parser = polygon + sep + uid + sep + county + sep + population

    result = parser.parseString(line)
    return result

def parse_lines(data, outfile):
    with open(outfile, 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
        lines = data.split('\n')
        for line in lines:
            if not line:
                continue
            points, uid, county, population = parse_line(line)
            for lat, long in points:
                writer.writerow([uid, county, population, lat, long])
            writer.writerow('')

parse_lines(data, r'd:\out.txt') # change the path to wherever you want output
```

Result:

```
101,Something,100000,12,13
101,Something,100000,22,23
101,Something,100000,16,17
101,Something,100000,22,24

102,another,200000,10,12
102,another,200000,40,42
102,another,200000,46,34
102,another,200000,16,24
102,another,200000,88,22
102,another,200000,33,24
102,another,200000,18,20
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for responding.I get below error,Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DURGA\Desktop\ttt.py", line 45, in <module>
    parse_lines(data, r'd:\out.txt')
  File "C:\Users\DURGA\Desktop\ttt.py", line 34, in parse_lines
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
TypeError: argument 1 must have a "write" method

Comment: Oh, sorry, I messed up. Let me fix that, just a minute.

Comment: @DurgaPrasadDhulipudi There we go. It ought to work now. Make sure to change `r'd:\out.txt'` to wherever you want to save the output. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thank you for showcasing [pyparsing](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing), it looks quite useful in addition to regex.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you senshin for the solution.That was my first attempt at Python.I tried your suggestion.Did try to work out alternative and got good result.

**Geometry,Zone,Type,UID**
"POLYGON(x1 y1,x2 y2,x3 y3,x4 y4)",name1,abc,100
"POLYGON(x1 y1,x2 y2,x3 y3,x4 y4,x5 y5,x6 y6)",name2,pqr,101

```
import csv
import re
import sys


l_InputFileName ='D:/Example1.txt'             # make changes here..
l_OutputFileName ='D:/Example1_o.txt'          # make changes here..

fo = open(l_OutputFileName, "a+")
with open( l_InputFileName, 'r') as csvfile:

csvR = csv.reader( csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
#Get first row which has column names
header = csvR.next()
#Convert first row which is a list into a string
print ','.join(header[0:])
#Write the header to output csv file,index starts at 1 here(splitting point into lat and        long)
fo.write('longitude,latitude,')
fo.write(','.join(header[1:])+'\n')

for row in csvR:

    #Remove the string POLYGON and brackets from first column
    coodlist=row[0].strip('POLYGON').strip('()').split(',')
    #Get the number of columns
    #print "\nNo of Columns="+str(len(row))
    #Get remaining columns 
    strRemainingCols =','.join(row[1:])
    #Print each lat,long in a seperate row..reamining columns will not change
    #Seperate latitude and longitude using comma
    for i in range(len(coodlist)):
       print coodlist[i].replace(' ',',')+','+strRemainingCols
       fo.write(coodlist[i].replace(' ',',')+','+strRemainingCols+'\n')

csvfile.close()
fo.close()
```